# .replace not removing characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

So I'm trying to convert PX to EM, but if a user enters `16px`, instead of `16` I want to strip the `PX`. Here's what I'm using

```
.replace(/^EM+/i, '')
```

But for some reason it's not removing.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xn9V/). Enter any value with `PX`, and you'll get `NaN`. Also is there a way to suppress the `NaN` so that then it won't show?

Comment: Change it to `px.replace(/PX$/i, '');` although `parseInt` might work for this particular case.

Comment: maybe `parseFloat()` will be better in this case since there can be also float values (`parseFloat` and `parseInt` will automatically skip `px` or `em`'s at the end)

Comment: Can you show a demo? @BogdanSavluk

Comment: @user302975 http://plnkr.co/edit/VQo0eWgjzgH9gi0g5rA3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is probably to just remove all characters that aren't `[0-9\.]` (a period or a number) on `keyup`. Then, you can perform the calculations and update the `<input>`s.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Ay56e/2/)

**HTML**

```
px <input type="text" id="px"> <br>
em <input type="text" id="em">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#px").keyup(function () {
    var px = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, "");   // replace all non 0-9 or .
    $(this).val(px);
    $("#em").val(parseInt(px)/16);               // set the value of em to px/16
})
$("#em").keyup(function(){
    var em = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, "");  // replace all non 0-9 or .
    $(this).val(em);
    $("#px").val(parseInt(em) * 16);            //set the value of px to em*16
})
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this is that the `^` character specifies the start of the line, and the `+` character is specifying that there must be at least one of them... [This example works](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/FDkLa/1/):

```
.replace(/EM+/i, '')
```

Comment: Perfect answer. One more question is how can I get rid of `NaN`. Because when the user is filling it in, and say they do `5e` while completing `5em`, it shows `NaN` in the PX box.

Comment: @user302975, you can use `parseFloat` and do not remove `em` in this particular case... or use `/em?/i` expression

Answer (score 0):

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FDkLa/

Don't use `^` as it tells to match **beginning** of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` matches the start of the string, so this will only remove px in the start. Use this instead:

```
.replace(/EM/i, '')
```

The `+` is also unnecessary; `M+` it matches 1 or more M's (e.g. "EMMM"  matches).

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

strips all characters leaving only numbers.  And no more NaN.

**EDIT:** Ok, fixed the problem with the huge number.

Confirm here [Latest Version](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj5cs/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.px').keyup(function () {
    var px = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');
    var rep = (px / 16);
    $('.em').val(rep);            
  });    
  $(".em").keyup(function () {
    var em = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');
    var rem = (em * 16);
    $('.px').replace().val(rem);
  });     
});
```

Comment: Go to the em section. Enter `15e`, get `NaN` in PX section.

Comment: Fixed the fiddle link.  Working now!

Comment: Nice, thanks. You answered both questions. But one problem. Enter the px, then get the em result. And re paste it into the em result. And it'll be a huge number

Comment: Ok, let me take another look

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this inside your event listener:

```
var val = this.value;
if (/^\d+(?:px)?$/i.test(val)) {
    // do conversion stuff
} else {
    // display error to user, perhaps a red border on the input
}
```